# Dynamic way to calculate the past 6 months Average

Tags: vba, pivot-table

The excel user will export the data from an online website to excel (12 months data), so the date will be all the time different.
I create a pivot table, and I have the months and total Average and Frequency. However, I need the 6 months as well, and I am not sure how to get it which time the data changes.

My question: is there any VBA code that will dynamically calculate the past 6 months Average?

Comment: It would be easier to do this referring to the raw data and not the pivot table.

Comment: Referring to the raw data a simple AVERAGEIFS() will do it without vba.

Comment: Even if the row data changes all the time? The pivot table is from the data. How could I do it direct from the data?

Comment: do you mean like a excel formula?

Comment: `=AVERAGEIFS(ValueColumn,DateColumn,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),DateColumn,"<" &TODAY()+1)`

Comment: That is a specific 6 months back, so it starts Oct 17 2019,  If you want to start on the 1st of Oct then use: `=AVERAGEIFS(ValueColumn,DateColumn,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-7)+1,DateColumn,"<" &TODAY()+1)`

Comment: in this case should be something like it `=AVERAGEIFS('12 Months'!F,'12 Months'!A">="EDATE(TODAY(),-6,'12 Months'!A,"<"`

Comment: `=AVERAGEIFS(F:F,A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),A:A,"<" &TODAY()+1)` that is if it is on the same sheet, otherwise you would need to add the sheet name: `Sheet1!F:F`

Comment: `=AVERAGEIFS('12 Months'!F:F,'12 Months'!A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6,'12 Months'!A:A,"<"&TODAY()+1`  I getting to many argument for this function error :/

Comment: `=AVERAGEIFS('12 Months'!F:F,'12 Months'!A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),'12 Months'!A:A,"<" &TODAY()+1)` you were missing a `)`

Comment: it worked, Thank you. would this formula work for frequency as well? (to do get the frequency I used the Amount in USD and change it to COUNT.

Comment: Change the `AVERAGEIFS('12 Months'!F:F,` to just `COUNTIFS(`

Comment: do you mean like this 
`=COUNTIFS('12 Months'!F:F,'12 Months'!A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),'12 Months'!A:A,"<"&TODAY()+1)`

Comment: `=COUNTIFS('12 Months'!A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),'12 Months'!A:A,"<"&TODAY()+1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner maybe could you create a answer so I could vote on it to mark as solved the question?

Comment: @ScottCraner maybe could you help me again. 
Seems like I need a way to calculate the average in the total months that the person did an action.
e.g _May, Jun, Aug, Nov 2019, and Apr -2020_ **the average and frequency of 6 months would only take in consideration this months**  _however, the data changes all the time and sometimes it will be more or less months_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do this with Formula.

To get the average of the past 6 months:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('12 Months'!F:F,'12 Months'!A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),'12 Months'!A:A,"<" &TODAY()+1)
```

To get the frequency:

```
=COUNTIFS('12 Months'!A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),'12 Months'!A:A,"<"&TODAY()+1)
```

If one wants the last 12 months, change the `-6` to `-12` in both formula.

Comment: Maybe could you help me again. Seems like I need a way to calculate the LAST 6 MONTHS AVERAGE in the total months that I have in the data e.g _May, Jun, Aug, Sep, Dec 2019, and Feb, Mar, Apr -2020_ so the it would only take in consideration this months. However, the data changes all the time and sometimes it will be more or less months.

Comment: New questions get new posts